# React setState doesn't work with Listener pattern

Tags: reactjs

My app tries to login at first. And I have an `isLoginTried` state that lets us know whether login has tried. Entry point of the App sets the login result listener on Login Component. And Login component posts the result by calling that listener function.

And Listener function set state `isLoginTried` as true. But when I logged it after `setState`, `isLoginTried` is still `false`!

I know `setState` function is asynchronous so I logged it with callback function of `setState`. My code snippet is below. Please give me some advices. Thank you.

+`MessageController` is an instance. So It can keep the listener functions.

```
// GlobalApp.tsx
class GlobalApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
      isLoginTried: false,
    }

    MessageController.setLoginResultListener(this.onLoginResult.bind(this));
  }

  ...

  onLoginResult(user: User) {
    this.setState({
      user,
      isLoginTried: true,
    }, () => { 
      console.log(this.state.isLoginTried); // it tells it's false!!
    }); 
  }
```

```
class UserDC() {
  login() { 
    ... 
    // This function always triggered
    // no matter login has been successful or not
    MessageController.postLoginResultListener(user); 
  }
}
```

`onLoginResult` of `GlobalApp` is executed! But it doesn't change state!

Comment: isLoginTired is spelled wrong, fix that first

Comment: @JREAM Thank you. It might've been tired....